# Development: How to download folder from OneDrive to personal compuer?

Tags: onedrive-for-business

I am doing something like below but always get exception which says resource not found. Is there something I need to do besides something below?

Please. Help.

```
var folderToCreate = new Item { Folder = new Folder() };
            var createdFolder = await oneDriveClient
                      .Drive
                      .Items[this.SelectedItem.Id]
                      .ItemWithPath("/path/to/my_folder")
                      .Request()
                      .CreateAsync(folderToCreate);
```